# Can init container be a kubernetes job

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to have a kubernetes job as init container for my kubernetes pod?

I want to start my kubernetes pod/ deployment only after the kubernetes job has successfully reached completed state. If above is not possible, is there any other way out? I can not use an external script to check `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete` etc and then start my pod.

Comment: I don't see a reason why you cannot run the containers that you run as a part of Job template within init Container , as soon it completes successfully , your container shall begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can safely use the same pod spec in Init container, as you used before in Job object. If you need to implement more sophisticated workflows please take a look at Argo Workflow framework - for doing things done on Kubernetes. [Here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/examples/README.md#conditionals) is an example of Conditionals usage.